# Javascript: Sort index array from zero

Tags: javascript

I have a simple Array

```
['one','two','three','four', 7: 'five']
```

I want the index is refresh and sorted again from zero, as you can see, `'five'` has `7` index, and it must be `4`

Please help me I'm a newbie in Javascript

Comment: It is not valid JavaScript

Comment: This is not valid JS syntax. Your question is not clear. What have you tried? What is the expected result?

Comment: @ScientiaEtVeritas Understand my problem, and save my time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 labels = labels.filter(() => true);
```

The `filter` method ignores indexes that don't exist (that are undefined), for example if you've used `delete labels[3];` or manually assigned value to indexes what will create gaps like `labels[100] = 100;` without assigning the values of the previous indexes (`99`, …).

The `filter` function returns a new array object with new indexes (so your 'five' with index 7 will be on index 4, as wished).

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jqf098hg/)**

Comment: No Problem :) If this or any answer has solved your question you can consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark on the left. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.